# Access Angular app running inside Docker container

Tags: angular, docker, dockerfile, redhat, redhat-containers

I've created a docker image to test an Angular app but I cannot connect from host to running app inside docker container.

The image was created using a Dockerfile with:
EXPOSE 4200 8080 80

I run the docker container with command:
docker run -ti -p 4200:4200 angulardev /bin/bash

Inside container I create the Angular application and start it using:
ng serve

From container, if I open localhost:4200 I see the application but I cannot access it from host OS (RHEL7)

What is wrong? The Angular app starts on port 4200 which is exposed and mapped to host 4200.

Thanks.

Comment: For Complete Docker beginners, learn how to run Angular inside Docker https://thecodeframework.com/run-angular-app-inside-a-docker-container-in-5-mins/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are running angular app inside your container with just `ng serve` it won't allow other hosts from accessing it.

Instead you should run it using `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200`

Comment: Thank You, Mike. I was running into this same issue and your suggestion made my day. Thanks again for the contribution.